# SQL Services delay to come back up after a server reboot in a Windows cluster

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

We have just built a 2-node Windows Server cluster and installed SQL 2019 configured with an Availability Group on both replicas.
I am still working on it, it is not live yet.

In the course of testing automatic failover, I am checking the behaviour of my configuration when each part fails. When I reboot node A, automatic failover happens quickly and both nodes are available within a short time. However, when I reboot node B, the server comes back up but the SQL Services are slow in starting. As slow as up to 30 minutes delay.

Is there a setting I need to look at in FCM or SSMS to fix this?

Also, please note that in FCM, I had changed number of failovers allowed from the default 1 failover in 6 hours to 1 failover in 0 hours. This could not possibly be causing the delayed SQL Services on B node?

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thank you

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by, "SQL Services are slow in starting." In an AG the SQL Instance is always running. If the service itself is taking a long time to start (aka run the executable) that's different than bringing a role or resource online in the cluster.

Comment: @SeanGallardy thanks for your time. So what happens is that in trying to test automatic failover with different scenarios. I found that if I reboot node A, automatic failover happens to B and the SQL services (in SSCM) on node A come back quickly as expected. However, when I reboot node B, automatic failover happens to A, but the services in SSCM delay in coming back up on node B. So, I'm wondering if there's a setting that could be influencing this in FCM or anywhere? The delay is about 30 minutes or even more. Any ideas please?

Comment: Ok, thanks for adding that. You'll need to check the windows event logs and any application logs to see if SQL Server is indeed being started at some previous point. This has nothing to really do with clustering per se, as clustering just happens to be installed on the server. The SQL Server service, outside of being an FCI, has no dependency on the cluster and will start whether or not the cluster is running.

Comment: @SeanGallardy I did have a look in Event logs, errorlogs and Cluster event logs but nothing reported. The only thing I noticed was that checking time stamps on the errorlogs, it stopped when the shutdown happened, but the new copy was not created until about 30 minutes after the last entry in the previous copy. The time between the last entry in the previous errorlog and the first entry in the new errorlog doesn't seem to have been reported anywhere from my searches. I will reproduce the issue again and re-check all logs. Thanks so much for your time and patience.